# Send a cross-domain ajax request using jQuery from phantom.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to test a chrome plugin by simulating part of what it's doing on phantomjs.

What I want phantom to do seems extremely simple, and yet I'm having problems. I want it to visit a certain web page and in the context of this page run a script that will send an ajax request to my backend and print out the response. To make my life easier, I want phantom to use jQuery for sending ajax requests.

So here’s the script `test1.js` that I’m passing to phantom:

```
var page = new WebPage(),
    url = 'http://www.example.com',

// Callback is executed each time a page is loaded...
page.open(url, function (status) {
  if (status === 'success') {
    console.log('opened url');
    start();
  }
});

function start(){
  page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function() {
    console.log("got here");
    $.get("http://my-wonderful-site.com")
      .done(function( data ) {
        console.log("here!");
        console.log(data);
        phantom.exit(); 
      });
  });
}
```

The console output of the command `phantomjs test1.js --web-security=false` is:

```
opened url
got here
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

  test1.js:20
  :/modules/webpage.js:337
```

So it seems that even jQuery doesn’t get loaded, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Tried page.injectJs to inject jQuery from my hard drive, but got the same error. Could you please help?

**Edited:**

Updated the function as suggested:

```
function start(){
  page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function() {
    console.log("got here");
    page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log("and here");
      $.get("http://my-wonderful-site.com")
        .done(function( data ) {
          console.log("here!");
          console.log(data);
          phantom.exit(); 
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Now phantom just hangs, and the console output is:

```
phantomjs test1.js --web-security=false
opened url
got here
```

That is, the console.log immediately before the `$.get` doesn't even execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS has two contexts. The inner context or page context is defined by `page.evaluate()`. It is sandboxed and has no access to variables defined outside. So, it doesn't know what `phantom` is. In the same way the outer context doesn't know what `$` is, because jQuery is a DOM library and was injected into the page. You need to wrap your jQuery request in `page.evaluate()`.

The other thing is that now, `phantom.exit()` doesn't mean anything. You need to tell PhantomJS to exit from inside of the page context, because the request is asynchronous. That's where the [`page.onCallback` and `window.callPhantom()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html) pair comes in.

```
page.onCallback = function(data){
  if (data.type === "exit") {
    phantom.exit();
  }
};

function start(){
  page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function() {
    console.log("got here");
    page.evaluate(function(){
      $.get("http://my-wonderful-site.com")
        .done(function( data ) {
          console.log("here!");
          console.log(data);
          window.callPhantom({type: "exit"});
        });
    });
  });
}
```

`console.log()` is defined inside of the page context, but you can't see it there, because PhantomJS doesn't pass them out by default. You have to register to the [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) event.

You can also send the data to the outer context with the help of `callPhantom()` instead of logging it. Note that not everything can be passed between the [contexts](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

The other helpful event handlers are [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) in case there are still problems.

Comment: Cool! Got it working using the page.onCallback and page.onConsoleMessage listeners. Incidentally, since I’m now listening to all console messages, I see lots of warnings like this: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL about:blank. Domains, protocols and ports must match.` Is this normal?

Comment: If you're using 1.9.8, then it is. It's simply a bug in PhantomJS that was introduced in version 1.9.8. It doesn't do anything and is only bad if you need clean output. I suggest that you update to PhantomJS 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to be in a `page.evaluate` to actually use the injected JS (see example here http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html). Try:

```
function start() {
    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function() {
        console.log("got here");
        page.evaluate(function() {
            $.get("http://my-wonderful-site.com")
            .done(function( data ) {
              console.log("here!");
              console.log(data);
              phantom.exit(); 
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah! This reminds me. I tried this before, and I tried this once again now (see update of my question). The error goes away, but now phantomjs just hangs immediately after `page.evaluate`. I put a logger before the `$.get`, but it doesn't print anything in the console.

Comment: Well now that's weird, you're definitely using the jQuery now at least. Just for the sake of debugging, add a `console.log` in the `.get` callback as well (`$.get("http://my-wonderful-site.com", function(){ console.log('derp'); })`). Does it at least hit that?

Comment: Nope :-( And I added a `console.log` on the line between `page.evaluate...` and `$.get` — and that `console.log` doesn't show up in the console either. So, technically, there’s even no way of saying that jQuery is being used, because the execution stops before it gets to `$.get`.

Comment: So basically, even if I remove the jQuery bit altogether and just write `    page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log("and here");
    });`, this freezes phantom when it gets to that point, and the log message does not even appear in the console.

Comment: Ahh whoops, I missed the log after the `page.eval`, you are 100% correct it's not getting there. Looking at some of my own tests, I am instantiating the page a bit differently- `var webPage = require('webpage'); var page = webPage.create();` instead of `var webPage = require('webpage'); var page = new webPage()`. Long shot, but worth a try?

Comment: Tried to instantiate the page like you did, but the problem is persisting. Just as a sanity check, I tried the first example from `http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html` (which uses page.evaluate, and it's working). So it must be me doing something wrong...

Comment: Yeah I did a straight copy pasta from the page-automation example with 100% success as well. It's got to be something stupid and minuscule, but seriously the only thing other than URIs that I see different between this broken example and working ones is the use of a `start()` function... but your namespaces seem right with the `page` var, so that can't be it. I've got nothing :(

Comment: Ok, I can at least avoid freezing phantomjs by doing this:  `var foo =  page.evaluate(function() {var test = "test"; return test; }); console.log(foo);`. Could it be that console.log (being a function) is not allowed inside page.evaluate? And, if so, could it be that ajax requests are also not allowed there?

Comment: Hmmmm functions are most definitely allowed, but maybe it has something to do with the promises (`.done()`). Working example of an Ajax in a `page.eval` is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705536/phantomjs-getting-value-out-of-page-evaluate-ajax-synchronous-version + a working `console.log` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415327/define-page-evaluate-outside-of-page-open-in-phantomjs  Doesn't explain why the `console.log` wasn't hit immediately after the `page.eval` though